# Using PHP to print Fibonacci series

Tags: php

I'm trying to print Fibonacci series using simple PHP program as shown below .

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fibonacci</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
        <table cellspacing="10px" rows="11" cols="2">        
            <?php  
            global $num0;
            global $num1;
            global $start;
            global $end;
            $start=0;
            $end=10;
            fibo(0,1,$start,$end);
            function fibo($num0,$num1,$start,$end){             
                    for($start;$start<$end;$start++){             
                              $sum=$num0+$num1;
                              $num0=$num1;
                              $num1=$sum;
                              echo "<tr><td>F<sub>$start</sub></td><td>$sum</td></tr>";                                    
                         }
            } 
            ?>
        </table>
            <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="<?php   fibo($num0, $num1, $start, $end+10)?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to print next fibonacci series when i click next.Please help me how to do this.I don't want to use Query String.

Comment: PHP executes on the server side, that onclick is going to be on the client-side you can't execute a PHP function from the client side.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of what PHP can do

Comment: While this question does demonstrate a misunderstanding of what PHP can do, I do not believe that meets the criteria of off-topic from what I can tell... If everyone here had an understanding of what they were asking, there wouldn't be any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're pretty far off. Your cannot use PHP this way.

PHP exists only on the server. The button you're clicking exists only in the browser. You cannot mix the two except via requests sent from the browser back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So, as  I said in my comment above, this isn't how PHP works. You could solve this purely in JavaScript and then you wouldn't involve PHP in anyway, OR if you don't want to use a query string and PHP is a must, then just use a $_SESSION variable to keep track of state.